# Why can't I change the size of a html post text input?

Tags: html, css

Okay, so I'm trying to make this bigger:

```
Post: <input id="postbox" type="text" rows="6" cols="40" name="post" />
```

But it's not reading the rows and cols.

Here is my css:

```
body{
    text-align: center;
    background-color: #000000;
}

h2{
    color: #0088AA;
    padding: 0px;
    margin: 0px;
}

#wrap{
    margin: auto;
    margin-top: -10px;
    margin-bottom: -10px;
    background-color: transparent !important;
    width: 700px;
    height: 100%;
    padding: 0px;
    text-align: left;
}

#postbox{
    background-color: #444444;
    border: 2px solid #777777;
    color: #ffffff;
}

.post{
    padding: 5px;
    margin-top: 10px;
    margin-bottom: 10px;
    background-color: #000044;
    border: 2px solid #443300;
    width: 100%;
    text-align: left;
    color: #007799;
}
```

Comment: `rows` and `cols` are for textareas. For textboxes you can use `width` and `height`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

probably you would need a `textarea` instead of an `input`

try this

```
<textarea id="postbox"  rows="6" cols="40" name="post"></textarea>
```

Answer (score 0):

First of all I can't see where you actually are changing the width property of the input element in your CSS.

The following CSS code is a direct reference to all input elements with the id=postbox AND the type="text".

```
input#postbox[type="text"]​​​​​{
width: 400px;
}​
```

Tjek this link to see it in action http://jsfiddle.net/sGpAf/

**EDIT**
This is of course if you wan't to use a single line textbox.. if you want to use multiline I strongly recommend a textarea instead :)

Answer (score -1):

hi y can define sapretly input tag selector css as like this

```
**css**   
 input[type="text"]{
width:200px;
    height:30px;
}


**html**

<input id="postbox" type="text" name="post" />
```

and now [check to](http://jsfiddle.net/PFmU2/2/)

http://jsfiddle.net/PFmU2/2/

Answer (score -1):

you may have type="search", which doesn't allow the height to be changed in some browsers.

Try changing it to type="text" or remove the type attribute altogether.

```
<input type="search">
<!-- remove type attribute so it becomes -->
<input>
```

jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/pby6u94k/

Answer (score -2):

If you don't want a textarea (i mean keeping the text on a single line) you can use the width and height attributes:

```
<input type='text' style='width:120px;height:50px;' />
```